# I'm trying to modify an MDX query to be dynamic in EazyBI, a Jira plugin

Tags: mdx, jira-plugin

We have this calculated member that adds a string whenever a specified calculated member reaches zero.

```
Case when
[Measures].[Burndown - Based on last 28 entries] < 0 AND 
([Measures].[Burndown - Based on last 28 entries],
 [Time].CurrentHierarchyMember.PrevMember) > 0
then 'ZBR'
end
```

we use this type of burndown with different lag(#) amount which creates multiple calculated members.

I am trying to change the code so that we don't need to create a calculated member for each new burndown member we create.

I've tried **measure.*** (code is invalid), **measure.all** (valid code but did nothing) and I didn't find much about this type of calculated member on the web.

Is it possible to have a calculated member that would output a string when any of the calculated used in the report reaches zero?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scope statement?

```
Scope(AddCalculatedMembers([Measures].Members));
    This = IIF([Measures].CurrentMember = 0, 'ZBR', [Measures].CurrentMember);
End Scope;
```

Comment: It gave me an error: 

    Formula is not valid: 
    Lexical error at line 1, column 47. Encountered: ";" (59), after : ""

Comment: Please read more about Scope usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/managing-scope-and-context-mdx